Returning all data if a an array parameter is empty in SQL
I'm a Frontend dev trying to work on a hobby project with supabase.
I have a supplies table with a name, company, type columns. company and type values is foreign keys & bound to supplies_companies & supplies_types tables respsectively.
I'm trying to add an RPC to fuzzy search supplies table that takes 3 parameters

query: string
companies: string[]
types: string[]

The function should behave as follows

Return all supplies If query is empty. Otherwise similar supplies names.
Return all supplies If companies is an empty array. Otherwise only return supplies where company column exists in companies parameter
types have the same conditions as companies.

My current code behaves as expected except in the case of passing empty arrays to companies & types it always returns an empty array where it should return all results. I don't know what I'm missing.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fuzzy_search_supplies(query TEXT, companies TEXT[], types TEXT[])
RETURNS SETOF supplies AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT s.*
  FROM supplies s
    
  WHERE (
    (
      query = '' -- Return all results if `query` is empty 
      OR similarity(s.name, query) > 0.2 -- Otherwise return rows with similar `name` to `query`
    )

    AND (
      companies IS NULL -- Return all companies if `companies` is empty 
      OR EXISTS (       -- Otherwise return rows with same `company`
        SELECT 1
        FROM unnest(companies) AS company
        WHERE s.company = company
      )
    )

    AND (      
      types IS NULL  -- Return all types if `types` is empty 
      OR EXISTS (    -- Otherwise return rows with same `type`
        SELECT 1
        FROM unnest(types) AS type
        WHERE s.type = type
      )
    )
  ); 
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


Instead of companies IS NULL try nullif(companies, '{}') is null. It will work correctly for both an empty array and a null value of companies. The same for types.
